# Removing need to prefix XPath paths with namespace?

Tags: .net, xpath

I'm new to XPath, so I hope I'm using the right terminology here...

I have a ~200k XML file I would like to parse with .Net XPath. I have tested my queries using an [online tool](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output) and have them working the way I want. However, when I use these same queries in .Net, they always return nothing.

After much fiddling, I found I could "fix" this problem by defining a namespace manager and then prefixing everything with that namespace:

```
XMLDoc = New XmlDocument()
XMLDoc.Load(FilePath)
mgr = New XmlNamespaceManager(XMLDoc.NameTable)
mgr.AddNamespace("a", "a.xsd")
Root = XMLDoc.DocumentElement
prop = Root.SelectSingleNode("//a:Properties/:PropertyData//a:boy/a:does/a:this/a:get/a:annoying", mgr)
```

Having to use the `a:` everywhere, and the `mgr`, makes the code somewhat harder to read and type. Is there a way I can fix this so that I don't need to have to sprinkle hundreds of `a:`'s everywhere?

Snippet of the file:

```
 <Properties>
    <PropertyData>
      <PropertyName>a place</PropertyName>
      <Address>APlace Road</Address>
      <City>NYC</City>
```